# Googlebot is scanning random link on my website

Tags: googlebot

Just take a look at this:

```
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:09:26 -0700] "GET /d733421/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:10:07 -0700] "GET /3e2b987/bz%E3%80%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%80%8D%E3%82%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E5%BC%BE%E3%81%8D%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%8Acover.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:10:48 -0700] "GET /3435e18/voice-angels-dj-darwin-yonatan-new.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:11:28 -0700] "GET /22ffa41/lambiyaan-si-judaiyaan-from-raabta-arijit-singh-shadab-altamash-faridi-jam8.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:12:09 -0700] "GET /fc49164/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:12:50 -0700] "GET /4783f2f/%E5%8A%89%E6%9B%89-%E4%B8%8D%E6%84%9B%E8%83%AD%E8%84%82%E6%84%9B%E4%B9%BE%E5%9D%A4-%E5%B0%88%E8%BC%AF%E3%80%90%E7%B5%95%E5%94%B14%E3%80%91.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:13:30 -0700] "GET /15c59b6/vet-lan-tram-studio-a.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:14:10 -0700] "GET /d91ad1d/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:14:51 -0700] "GET /7950d9d/nui-harimes-theme-music-kill-la-kill.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:15:31 -0700] "GET /9ff60ea/02-up-the-hill-backwards.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:16:12 -0700] "GET /d1565f4/background-music-of-bate-ye-kabhi-na-tu-bhulna-without-lyric.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:16:52 -0700] "GET /efbb05e/huyen-thoai-me-thanh-le-mau.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:17:33 -0700] "GET /3db632d/mahi-tu-dil-rhi-tu-aashiq-ki-sachi-gawahi-tu-songs-download.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:18:13 -0700] "GET /dc4c042/solo-guitar-vung-la-me-bay-sieu.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:18:54 -0700] "GET /29e20e4/%E3%80%8A%E5%AF%92%E9%B8%A6%E5%AC%89%E6%B0%B4%E3%80%8B%E8%92%8B%E5%A9%B7.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:19:34 -0700] "GET /488f587/ninaivellam-nithya-1982-song-mp3.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:20:15 -0700] "GET /1d3f61f/dubstep-apocalypse-from-singomakers-389-samples.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:20:55 -0700] "GET /5d3405d/la-fuaten-durma.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:21:36 -0700] "GET /a372d3b/jibon-britter-gaan.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:22:17 -0700] "GET /d14c2b3/16-michael-devellis-funky.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:22:57 -0700] "GET /c0d7931/chumlung-bangkok-chandrawati-tapebung-limbu.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:23:37 -0700] "GET /c33ca0e/catas-remember.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:24:18 -0700] "GET /595da7b/ensemble-xacara-falla-con-misuras-guiglielmo-ebreo.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:24:59 -0700] "GET /f2d6060/grey-90s-old-school-hip-hop.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:25:39 -0700] "GET /b9b2b5e/learn-to-play-guitar-subliminal-ambient-music-therapy-9.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:26:20 -0700] "GET /6502836/nau-banh-dem-xuan-tan-co.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:27:00 -0700] "GET /52bff1c/baadal-single-by-sherrin-varghese-mp3.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:27:41 -0700] "GET /d3a98a4/shubhechha-mohanty-song-tere-sang-yaara.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:28:21 -0700] "GET /c57ebc1/long-me-2-duy-phuong-hat.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:29:02 -0700] "GET /2e709b5/mujhe-pyar-hua-allah-miya-dj-rex-free-download.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:29:42 -0700] "GET /52cb0a7/mai-minh-cuoi-so-06.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:30:23 -0700] "GET /d163f3b/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:31:03 -0700] "GET /4e65ec9/jindgiek-gharhai-dj.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:31:44 -0700] "GET /a6ec801/kantik-sean-paul-get-busy.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:32:24 -0700] "GET /c811747/saltuk-erginer-saatler-2009.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:33:05 -0700] "GET /54dd066/%E5%8A%89%E7%A7%80%E8%8E%B2-march-2014-performance-sunrise.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.24 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:33:09 -0700] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 301 453 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:33:10 -0700] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:33:45 -0700] "GET /e436502/vietsub-mi-muc-nhu-hoa-%E7%9C%89%E7%9B%AE%E5%A6%82%E7%94%BB.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:34:26 -0700] "GET /58e1608/ala-baburawedj-dot-in.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:35:06 -0700] "GET /f333b20/lirik-lagu-alan-walker-sing-me-to-sleep-terjemahan-nya.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:35:47 -0700] "GET /309b83b/meri-binthi-yahi-dj-song.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:36:28 -0700] "GET /97a4f29/nee-vupiri-na-sonthama.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:37:08 -0700] "GET /d1dfa5d/the-tidy-carnival-subway-city-may-28th.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:37:49 -0700] "GET /1495858/pankhida-o-pankhida-original-shree-mahakali-chalisa-hemant-chauhan.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:38:29 -0700] "GET /80f2e26/miss-neelam-bhakti-song.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:39:10 -0700] "GET /e20487c/oguzhan-koc-ft-gulben-ergen-askla.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:39:50 -0700] "GET /6d57895/rain-on-the-roof-cover-by-the.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:40:31 -0700] "GET /e2f1c5b/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:41:11 -0700] "GET /f87b0f1/instrumental-of-creature-3d-hum-rahe-ya-na.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:41:52 -0700] "GET /aa420ea/paylnaman-song-dj.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:42:32 -0700] "GET /abdc0f9/daniella-canta-aguenta-coracao-versao-ii.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:43:13 -0700] "GET /f2db465/original-sin-red-mist.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:43:53 -0700] "GET /bf16ce2/jab-tak-armaan-malik-house-remix-lahoria.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:44:34 -0700] "GET /04c4896/arctic-moon-vs-bryan-kearney-activate.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:45:14 -0700] "GET /afa8d08/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:45:55 -0700] "GET /d947abc/loi-me-hat-my-linh-demo.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:46:35 -0700] "GET /a5fd9d6/alif-laila-in-hindi-part-2-the-arabian-nights.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:47:16 -0700] "GET /913a0e3/tink-m-e-n-lyrics.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:47:56 -0700] "GET /7f1c06a/badal-bijli-chandan-pani-dowload.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:48:37 -0700] "GET /62265d1/chal-beta-selfi-lele-re-gujarati-dandiya.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:49:17 -0700] "GET /5f42ec1/gui-nguoi-yeu-cu.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:49:58 -0700] "GET /21d973d/dark-world-remix-by-summonersjukebox-zelda30thanniversary-party.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:50:39 -0700] "GET /ea4d11f/na-marr-zalma-ve-old-punjabi-song-by-ranjit-kaur-download.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:51:19 -0700] "GET /e968192/wedding-dard-karara.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:52:00 -0700] "GET /80df7c7/straight-up-paula-abdul-lyrics.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:52:40 -0700] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 304 164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:52:40 -0700] "GET /530923b/marjan-khir-mohamad-badakhshi-shana-bjomban-mp3-songs.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:53:21 -0700] "GET /f610da9/oi-akash-ghire-sondhya-name.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:54:01 -0700] "GET /1b14ac1/the-best-of-vocal-deep-house-2017.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:54:42 -0700] "GET /887ff11/richard-marx-ask-richard-part-3.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:55:22 -0700] "GET /a88ac73/pk-song-mp3.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:56:03 -0700] "GET /618b136/%E5%BD%AD%E4%BD%B3%E6%85%A7%E3%80%8C%E5%A4%A7%E9%BD%A1%E5%A5%B3%E5%AD%90%E3%80%8D-cover.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:56:43 -0700] "GET /a72edd8/download-mere-baap-ki-gaadi-song.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:57:24 -0700] "GET /55c1550/deniz-ustunde-fener-selcuk-balci-official.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:58:04 -0700] "GET /7aaa105/radyo-mega-20-ekim-2015-gulben-ergen.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:58:45 -0700] "GET /41ad9db/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:20:59:25 -0700] "GET /e519141/house-logic-pro-x-template-were-stars.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:00:06 -0700] "GET /391e69e/radhe-shyam-radhe-shyam-%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE-%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE-naam.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:00:46 -0700] "GET /d2e4eb0/dard-e-disco-52-sizzling-non-stop-hits-2007-mp3-songs.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:01:27 -0700] "GET /0d84ff6/tarling-pengen-dueni-anica-nada.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:02:07 -0700] "GET /aa6cb5e/%E1%9E%A2%E1%9E%84%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%82%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%9F%E1%9E%B7%E1%9E%91%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%92%E1%9E%B7%E1%9E%98%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%BB%E1%9E%9F%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9F%E1%9E%A2%E1%9E%93%E1%9F%92.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:02:48 -0700] "GET /14b7e61/hare-krishna-bhajans-ke-anilo-re.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:03:29 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5483 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:04:09 -0700] "GET /3d3980e/bima-jantara-02.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:04:50 -0700] "GET /274a066/www-ollywood-gruha-laxmi-old-mp3-songs-nic-in.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 209.141.61.146 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:05:31 -0700] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1497413130.9266519546508789062500 HTTP/1.1" 200 403 "http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1497413130.9266519546508789062500" "WordPress/4.6.6; http://example.com"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:05:30 -0700] "GET /210facf/lay-lay-bai-vadyavar-ya-song-vipmarathi.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:06:11 -0700] "GET /055be15/jatti-nachdi-ks-makhan-remix.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:06:51 -0700] "GET /8ab9855/chitarkut-ke-dham-pe-superhit-haryanvi.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:07:32 -0700] "GET /d13b88f/fields-of-doom.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:08:12 -0700] "GET /d12f289/hh-indradyumna-swami-lessons-learned.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:08:53 -0700] "GET /e7517c7/goran-maa-de-lal-nu-feroz-khan.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:09:33 -0700] "GET /f8751f2/satinder-sartaaj-cheerey-waalea-live.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:09:37 -0700] "GET /ec0ce74/tulus-ruang-sendiri-ucin-cover.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:10:14 -0700] "GET /6553ca1/durnbir-saha-adriza-aa-ja-sanam-madhur-chandni-mp3-songs.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:10:54 -0700] "GET /fdd0f05/kun-anta-humood-alkhudher-cover.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:11:35 -0700] "GET /ea56f78/jai-shree-ram-sare-jaha-se-acha-mix-mp3-song.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:12:15 -0700] "GET /b0741b6/mera-joota-h-japani-robot-mixx-download.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:12:56 -0700] "GET /e256fff/meri-ardas-data-tere-charna-vich-bhajan-dera-sacha-sauda.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:13:36 -0700] "GET /e27493f/cest-la-vie-papa-vicky-leandros.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:14:17 -0700] "GET /fbed8a2/lakdi-ki-kathi-remix-song-download.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:14:57 -0700] "GET /8b76534/euphoric-sufis-mp3-songs.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:15:38 -0700] "GET /86b86e8/top-chinese-song-2013.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:16:19 -0700] "GET /aad5994/vs-meu-amanha.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:16:59 -0700] "GET /7738e54/dj-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B0-126-song-2017-com.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:17:40 -0700] "GET /f5ded34/teri-jai-jai-jai-ho-ganesh-ji.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:18:20 -0700] "GET /f12f16c/helen-henny-i-knew-you-we-re-trouble.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:19:01 -0700] "GET /ed96d39/new-ganapati-garba-mr-jatt.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:19:41 -0700] "GET /409b325/orys-creole-trombone-turk-murphyclimax-jb.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:20:22 -0700] "GET /a433366/ceva-de-la-banat-korg-pa4x.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:21:02 -0700] "GET /8359c32/%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%98%E0%B8%B8%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%84%E0%B9%8C%E0%B8%9C%E0%B8%B9%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A3.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:21:43 -0700] "GET /6770d24/rick-ross-maybach-music-type-beat.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.20 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:22:23 -0700] "GET /0622d1c/%E7%8F%8D%E5%A6%AE%E5%A8%83%E5%A8%83.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:23:04 -0700] "GET /8cc19fe/tere-bina-nai-jina-re-ro-ro-ke-mar-jana.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:23:44 -0700] "GET /c6ac658/kaaze-presents-showkaaze-ep-minimix.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:24:25 -0700] "GET /85d0fce/ali-in-my-dream%EF%BC%88%E9%BB%83%E9%87%91%E5%B8%9D%E5%9C%8Bost-part-2%EF%BC%89%E4%B8%AD%E5%AD%97%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.16 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:25:05 -0700] "GET /a5ec1c2/khal-racha-kismat-ne-kuch-tokhal-to-fer-mp3-song.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:25:46 -0700] "GET /54b5039/www-kannad-bhajan-akash-managuli.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.18 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:26:26 -0700] "GET /8e40abc/example.com HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.14 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:27:07 -0700] "GET /c522d33/edm-night-angry-bull-51416.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:27:47 -0700] "GET /fafde55/susta-pawan-sanga-nepali-song-promo.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:28:28 -0700] "GET /1d5cbfb/dustin-savage-shes-my-kinda-crazy.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:29:08 -0700] "GET /d701803/lagu-lesti-saya-sang-bintang-pentas.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:29:49 -0700] "GET /90d7ff5/vbs-29-05-2017-sadabahar-geet.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
example.com:80 66.249.79.12 - - [13/Jun/2017:21:30:29 -0700] "GET /980c276/kaya-padam-padam.html HTTP/1.1" 404 16729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I just have a WordPress installed on that domain and there's nothing more there!
There are thousands of hits like this.
How can I stop it?

Comment: *How can I stop it?* For the most part, you can't. Just make sure your site is not hacked. These açcesses indicate that your site was/is a target of an attack. It is very common that WP site are targets of scripted attacks and açcesses of this type indicate that the attacking site thinks your site has already been compromised.

Comment: I was not entirely clear. These açcesses are coming from Google, however, the links that Google is following are from the attacking site. Otherwise, the links would not exist. To know the attacking sites, perhaps these links will show up in Googles Search Console.

Comment: Possibly URLs from a site that used to be on the same domain?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No all the links are random stuffs that have nothing to do with my website!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller These açcesses are a classic WP hack. It does not have to be WP, however, this is quite common. What happens is that a compromised computer attempts to infect other WP installs and creates links to what it expects to be valid URLs. If the attempt to infect fails, it does not matter. This is script kiddie stuff and therefore not terribly sophisticated. What is important is the number of infected systems.

Comment: Those links point to some Indian songs. I think may be in past someone use [grabber script](https://master-land.net/Thread-Pagalworld-Grabber-For-Sale) to generate those pages from popular website like pagal-world and mr jatt. Is it new domain? Have you check that [domain history on web archive](https://web.archive.org)? If the domain is already used in past, then Google may try to crawl those pages again. I don't think hack script point to such a webpages.

Answer (score 3):

When a site is put up for the public to see, Google will, at some point, try to index it.

Based on your logs, it's likely that someone managed to install a special script on the server in the past that created random directories containing random files with at least one file being linked from your domain name itself or an important page linked from your domain name itself.

Since then, something or someone has removed those random directories and/or files which is why the number 404 appears in the logs after "HTTP/1.1". 404 in the web world is the code that represents that the required core file (example: index.html) to process the HTML requested was "Not found".

Now if such actions did not happen on your server, then the only other possibility would be that someone went into your Google Search Console account and uploaded a site map containing all of the URL fragments listed in your logs (example: /ed96d39/new-ganapati-garba-mr-jatt.html). Uploading sitemaps is a way to assist Google in locating all of your public-facing URLs on your web server and Google will scan each and every URL.